# Event ID ( 11 ) running weblogic as a Windows service

Tags: windows, weblogic

we are running Weblogic 10.0MP1 as a Windows service (Win2003 server).
Often, in windows application event log, we have this kind of message:

1/9/2012    10:13:06 PM beasvc  Warning None    11  N/A MYSERVERNAME    The description for Event ID ( 11 ) in Source ( beasvc ) cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer. You may be able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to retrieve this description; see Help and Support for details. The following information is part of the event: MYSERVICENAME

Besides the fact that we are investigating on why the description of the event cannot be found, is there anyone that knows what Event ID 11 represents for beasvc?

Comment: This post kind of explains the details behind the event viewer message but it is not particularly helpful to troubleshoot a Weblogic outage: http://www.eventlogblog.com/blog/2008/04/event-log-message-files-the-de.html. Did you find something new about it?

Answer (score 0):

I was googling about this message because I just had to investigate the same issue, in the end, I've found out that my whole server (where I had my Weblogic Admin Server) was restarted by some other team, hence the following error message:

```
<BEA-002634> <The server "AdminServer" disconnected from this server.>
```

and this weird warning on event viewer. If you research about this id + the beasvc process, you will find several different explanations related to missing DLLs or windows registry misconfiguration (e.g., `https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=875675`) but, in this case, it means that the service was abruptly stopped by the Server.